# How to check XON/XOFF of the server from the client in c++ while using TCP/IP connection socket?

Tags: c++

how to check XON/XOFF of the server, to check the socket is alive or not. there is a problem of TCP half close, where sending data but server is not receiving by being alive. It is sending XON/XOFF for every 2 mins, is there any way that i detect and reconnect , if i don't get any signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a *keep-alive* signal being sent by the server, then just wait until you don't receive it anymore (twice the time of the keep-alive period is a safe value), and reconnect.

Comment: Not set the keep - alive option to the socket.

Comment: @Ershad The default timeout for `SO_KEEPALIVE` (which I guess you meant) is on most systems two hours. So it's not a good alternative in most cases.

Comment: So, What is the best solution to check server connection is proper?

Comment: @Ershad You state that the server should send XON/XOFF every two minutes? That is yous keep-alive signal. If you don't receive it in, lets say, four minutes then reconnect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Right sir, i should check every 2 or 4 minutes to check is it alive by checking for XON and XOFF.